# How let QTableView show header label when initial

Tags: python, qtableview

I used QTableView and QAbstractTableModel to show my data,

When I startup my MainFrame , there is nothing in the QTableView , because I don't
set the data into TableModel ,

but I want to show Header , how can I do it ?

There is sample code

```
class MainFrame(QMainFrame):
    ....do something...
    self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralWidget)
    self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 531, 161))
    self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
    self.myModel = MyModel(self)
    # self.myModel.update([[1, 2], [2, 3]])
    self.tableView.setModel(self.myModel)
    ....do something....
```

and MyModel Class,

```
class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    header_labels = ['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4','Column5']
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.datatable = None

    def update(self, dataIn):
        .....
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        .....
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        .....
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        .....
    def flags(self, index):
        .....
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.header_labels[section]
        return QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)
```

Comment: the scenario is that , I startup app -> click btn -> show data at tableview , then
I don't have data at first time ,but I want to show header label

Comment: It should work without the last line. Returning a static method call is not going to do anything. Also you shouldn't have to check the role, only the orientation. Therefore you don't need the `if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole`